# Getting "Variable is not Defined" error in Inline Editing

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce, inlineeditsupport

I have created a Visualforce Page which is displaying the Child related list as inline on Parent record detail page. Also I have used the inlineEditsupport to edit the child records by double clicking it.

Here is the code snippet of VF page i have used to inline editing :

```
<apex:outputField value="{!invcLine.Name}" >
    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
</apex:outputField>
```

The problem i am facing is when I double click to edit the record the inline editing is not working and in the console its showing this error:

[image]

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Perf is not defined"

Comment: is this an embedded VF ?

Answer (score 1):

Following a ticket we have made to the salesforce support, they deployed the patch 208.5 / Summer '17 Patch 4.5.

The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It is known issue on salesforce, after summer 17 release, and they scheduled to fix on path 5.0, Check the link

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CYWQA2&title=inline-edit-not-working-on-embedded-visualforce-page

Here is the workaround that works for me!

```
window.enablePerf = function(window) {
    'use strict';
    var a = { DEBUG: { name: "DEBUG", value: 1 }, INTERNAL: { name: "INTERNAL", value: 2 }, PRODUCTION: { name: "PRODUCTION", value: 3 }, DISABLED: { name: "DISABLED", value: 4 } };
    window.PerfConstants = { PAGE_START_MARK: "PageStart", PERF_PAYLOAD_PARAM: "bulkPerf", MARK_NAME: "mark", MEASURE_NAME: "measure", MARK_START_TIME: "st", MARK_LAST_TIME: "lt", PAGE_NAME: "pn", ELAPSED_TIME: "et", REFERENCE_TIME: "rt", Perf_LOAD_DONE: "loadDone", STATS: { NAME: "stat", SERVER_ELAPSED: "internal_serverelapsed", DB_TOTAL_TIME: "internal_serverdbtotaltime", DB_CALLS: "internal_serverdbcalls", DB_FETCHES: "internal_serverdbfetches" } };
    window.PerfLogLevel = a;
    var b = window.Perf = {
        currentLogLevel: a.DISABLED,
        mark: function() { return b },
        endMark: function() { return b },
        updateMarkName: function() { return b },
        measureToJson: function() { return "" },
        toJson: function() { return "" },
        setTimer: function() { return b },
        setServerTime: function() { return b },
        toPostVar: function() { return "" },
        getMeasures: function() { return [] },
        getBeaconData: function() { return null },
        setBeaconData: function() {},
        clearBeaconData: function() {},
        removeStats: function() {},
        stat: function() { return b },
        getStat: function() { return -1 },
        onLoad: function() {},
        startTransaction: function() { return b },
        endTransaction: function() { return b },
        updateTransaction: function() { return b },
        isOnLoadFired: function() { return !1 },
        util: { setCookie: function() {} },
        enabled: !1
    };
};
```

Upload this js as a static resource and on your page call the following piece of code on window load or whatever you call on page init.

```
if(!this["Perf"]){
                window.enablePerf(this);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you getting this issue, but try to Import
"require('react-addons-perf');" to your code. Like
" var Perf = require('react-addons-perf'); "